# need help with Brocade switch

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, switch

How do i find the Area ID in brocade switch and what command will help me see the HBA wwn and storage port connected to the brocade switch.

please help gui/Cli ..
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh how we've missed your questions Wildchild!

The 'portswapshow' command will tell you a particular area ID, oh and can I ask you to rewrite the second part of your question, it's unclear what you mean (you probably just need either the 'fwportshow' or 'fwportdetailshow' commands).